Error experienced when using mixed-effects random forest (MERF) in LongituRF
I have been using LongituRF to run mixed-effects random forest models, and have a question RE the predict.longituRF() function.
I have created a MERF using training data (n = 222), and want to use this model fit to predict on a subset (test data, n = 75). However, when I use the code:
predictions_merf_df <- predict(
    object = MERF_bird_Shannon,
    X = data.frame(Test_list$X),
    id = Test_list$id,
    Z = Test_list$Z,
    time = Test_list$time)

I receive the error:
Error in Ypred[w] <- f[w] + Z[w, , drop = FALSE] %*% 
    object$random_effects[k, :
    replacement has length zero

I have hit a bit of a wall, and would appreciate insight if anyone is willing to share.

Questions solely about how software works are
off-topic
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you
understand the statistical concepts involved, the
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least
easy to get from the documentation.
